# How to access ejabberd web console after connecting it to mysql?

Tags: mysql, xmpp, ejabberd

I am new to ejabberd. I have connected ejabberd to mysql. Users are registering successfully but i can't access the ejabberd web console. It is giving error on ejabberdctl live-

```
W(<0.348.0>:ejabberd_web_admin:224) : Access of "admin" from "127.0.0.1" failed with error:  "bad-password"
```

i have register admin with following command and it has successfully registered users in mysql.

```
ejabberdctl register admin localhost password
```

The lines of ejabberd.cfg file which i changed to connect to mysql are as follows-

```
{auth_method, odbc}.
%% To use both anonymous and internal authentication:
{host_config, "public.example.org", [{auth_method, [odbc, anonymous]}]}.
{odbc_server, "DSN=testing;UID=root;PWD=india"}.
{acl, admin, {user, "admin", "localhost"}}.

{mod_last_odbc,     []},
{mod_offline_odbc,  [{access_max_user_messages, max_user_offline_messages}]},
{mod_privacy_odbc,  []},
{mod_private_odbc,  []},
{mod_pubsub_odbc,   [
              {access_createnode, pubsub_createnode},
              {ignore_pep_from_offline, true}, % reduces resource comsumption, but XEP incompliant
              %%{ignore_pep_from_offline, false},  % XEP compliant, but increases resource comsumption
              {last_item_cache, false},
              {plugins, ["flat", "hometree", "pep"]}  % pep requires mod_caps
             ]},
{mod_roster_odbc,   []},
{mod_vcard_odbc,    []},
```

Please response with the answer. I got stuck in this problem.

On startup ejabberd using - ejabberdctl live, the following report is also shown-

```
=INFO REPORT==== 2013-12-29 16:48:05 ===
I(<0.40.0>:cyrsasl_digest:44) : FQDN used to check DIGEST-MD5 SASL authentication:
```

Does it affect anything in authenticating? I am using ejabberd- 2.1.12 and mysql 5.5

Comment: if you read carefully, it says you have BAD PASSWORD. please check ur password, blank / caps, before you pull ur hair out.

Comment: I have checked it... It is correct. I dont know why it is giving error in password

Comment: I have added some more info in question... Please help...

Answer (score 1):

My problem is solved after reinstalling erlang from source "otp_src_R15B". There was a problem in erlang.